# Scroll an overflow component in react/next

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

So I have a component that have a fixed width with an overflow-x-auto. I decided to hide the scroll bar and replace it with 2 arrow/button both left and right. If I click left, it scroll to left and vice versa. How can I achieve this functionality ?

this is my component

```
<div className={` vertical-card w-7/12 flex flex-row overflow-x-scroll no-scrollbar pb-4`}>
            {
                dataConselor.map((item, index) => {
                    return <VerticalCard key={item.id} name={item.nama} specialist={item.specialist} shortdesc={item.shortdesc} img={item.img} />
                })
            }

        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Target the scrollable element (you can use useRef, since it's react):

```
const scrollable = useRef(null);

<div id="myElement" ref={scrollable}>
...
</div>
```

2. Create the scroll function:

```
const scrollIt = (toRight) => {
  const scrollLength = ... //Calculate your scroll length however you want.
  scrollable.current.scrollBy({left: scrollLength * (toRight ? 1 : -1), behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

3. Add this function to the left/right buttons:

```
<div id="toLeft" onClick={()=>scrollIt(false)}>...</div>
<div id="toRight" onClick={()=>scrollIt(true)}>...</div>
```

Comment: do you have any link for documentation of the "current" object? I might need it later becasuse I need the percentage of scroll progress (0-100).

Answer (score 1):

As you are using tailwind css, you can use a tailwind carousal component to achieve this behaviour.

There are various carousals available over [here](https://As%20you%20are%20using%20tailwind%20css.%20You%20can%20use%20a%20carousal).